# Creating a fold that allows the type to change after each repeated function call, in order to call a function n times without recursion

Tags: haskell, type-systems, type-level-computation, clash

I am trying to use a dfold defined [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.11/docs/CLaSH-Sized-Vector.html#g:19)

```
dfold 
    :: KnownNat k    
    => Proxy (p :: TyFun Nat * -> *)    
    -> (forall l. SNat l -> a -> (p @@ l) -> p @@ (l + 1))  
    -> (p @@ 0) 
    -> Vec k a  
    -> p @@ k
```

Basically it is a fold that allows you to return a new type after each cycle.

I am trying to generalize the **bitonicSort** defined in this project: 
https://github.com/adamwalker/clash-utils/blob/master/src/Clash/Sort.hs

I two functions that are important for the types that the dfold with generate:

```
bitonicSort
    :: forall n a. (KnownNat n, Ord a)
    => (Vec n a -> Vec n a)             -- ^ The recursive step
    -> (Vec (2 * n) a -> Vec (2 * n) a) -- ^ Merge step
    -> Vec (2 * n) a                    -- ^ Input vector
    -> Vec (2 * n) a                    -- ^ Output vector
bitonicMerge
    :: forall n a. (Ord a , KnownNat n)
    => (Vec n a -> Vec n a) -- ^ The recursive step
    -> Vec (2 * n) a        -- ^ Input vector
    -> Vec (2 * n) a        -- ^ Output vector
```

The example used in the project mentioned above is:

```
bitonicSorterExample 
    :: forall a. (Ord a) 
    => Vec 16 a -- ^ Input vector
    -> Vec 16 a -- ^ Sorted output vector
bitonicSorterExample = sort16
    where
    sort16 = bitonicSort sort8 merge16
    merge16 = bitonicMerge merge8

    sort8  = bitonicSort  sort4  merge8
    merge8 = bitonicMerge merge4

    sort4  = bitonicSort  sort2 merge4
    merge4 = bitonicMerge merge2

    sort2  = bitonicSort  id merge2
    merge2 = bitonicMerge id
```

I went ahead and made a more general version.

```
genBitonic :: (Ord a, KnownNat n) =>
  (Vec n a -> Vec n a, Vec (2 * n) a -> Vec (2 * n) a)
  -> (Vec (2 * n) a -> Vec (2 * n) a, Vec (4 * n) a -> Vec (4 * n) a)
genBitonic (bSort,bMerge) = (bitonicSort bSort bMerge, bitonicMerge bMerge)

bitonicBase :: Ord a =>  (Vec 1 a -> Vec 1 a, Vec 2 a -> Vec 2 a)
bitonicBase = (id, bitonicMerge id)
```

With this version I can quick make new Bitonic Sorts like so:

```
bSort16 :: Ord a => Vec 16 a -> Vec 16 a
bSort16 = fst $ genBitonic $ genBitonic $ genBitonic $ genBitonic bitonicBase

bSort8 :: Ord a => Vec 8 a -> Vec 8 a
bSort8 = fst $ genBitonic $ genBitonic $ genBitonic bitonicBase

bSort4 :: Ord a => Vec 4 a -> Vec 4 a
bSort4 = fst $ genBitonic $ genBitonic bitonicBase

bSort2 :: Ord a => Vec 2 a -> Vec 2 a
bSort2 = fst $ genBitonic bitonicBase
```

Each Sort with work with a vector of the specified size.

```
testVec16 :: Num a => Vec 16 a
testVec16 =  9 :> 2 :> 8 :> 6 :> 3 :> 7 :> 0 :> 1 :> 4 :> 5 :> 2 :> 8 :> 6 :> 3 :> 7 :> 0 :> Nil

testVec8 :: Num a => Vec 8 a
testVec8 =  9 :> 2 :> 8 :> 6 :> 3 :> 7 :> 0 :> 1 :> Nil

testVec4 :: Num a => Vec 4 a
testVec4 =  9 :> 2 :> 8 :> 6 :> Nil

testVec2 :: Num a => Vec 2 a
testVec2 =  2 :> 9 :>  Nil
```

**Quick notes:**

- I am trying to the apply "genBitonic" to "bitonicBase" t times.
- I am using CLaSH to synthesis this to VHDL, so I cannot use recursion to apply t times
- We will always be sorting a vec size 2^t in to a vec of the same size
- "Vec n a"  is a vector of size n and type a

I would like to make a function that generates the function for a given Vec. I believe using dfold or dtfold, is the correct path here.

I wanted to do the fold with something like the function `genBitonic`.

Then use `fst` to get the function I need for sorting.

I had two possible designs:

**One**: Fold using composition to get a Function that that takes a base.

```
bSort8 :: Ord a => Vec 8 a -> Vec 8 a
bSort8 = fst $ genBitonic.genBitonic.genBitonic $ bitonicBase
```

Before the base was replied it would have resulted in something like

```
**If composition was performed three times**

foo3 ::
  (Ord a, KnownNat n) =>
  (Vec n a -> Vec n a, Vec (2 * n) a -> Vec (2 * n) a)
  -> (Vec (2 * (2 * (2 * n))) a -> Vec (2 * (2 * (2 * n))) a,
      Vec (4 * (2 * (2 * n))) a -> Vec (4 * (2 * (2 * n))) a)
```

**Two**: 
 Second idea was to use the bitonicBase as the value b to start accumulation on. This would have resulted directly in the form I need it in before I apply `fst`.

**Edit**
`vecAcum` is just meant to be the value building up inside of the `dfold`.

In the dfold example they fold using a `:>` which is just the vector form of the list operator `:`

```
>>> :t (:>)
(:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (n + 1) a
```

What I want to do is take a tuple of two functions like:

```
genBitonic :: (Ord a, KnownNat n) =>
  (Vec n a -> Vec n a, Vec (2 * n) a -> Vec (2 * n) a)
  -> (Vec (2 * n) a -> Vec (2 * n) a, Vec (4 * n) a -> Vec (4 * n) a)
```

And compose them. 
So `genBitonic . genBitonic` would have type:

```
(Vec n a -> Vec n a, Vec (2 * n) a -> Vec (2 * n) a)
-> (Vec (2 * (2 * n)) a -> Vec (2 * (2 * n)) a, Vec (4 * (2 * n)) a -> Vec (4 * (2 * n)) a)
```

So then the base function would be what solidifies the types. 
e.g.

```
bitonicBase :: Ord a =>  (Vec 1 a -> Vec 1 a, Vec 2 a -> Vec 2 a)
bitonicBase = (id, bitonicMerge id)
bSort4 :: Ord a => Vec 4 a -> Vec 4 a
bSort4 = fst $ genBitonic $ genBitonic bitonicBase
```

I am using the dfold to build the function for Vectors of length n that is equivalent to doing the recursion on a vector of length n.

**I tried:**

I tried to follow the example listed under dfold

```
data SplitHalf (a :: *) (f :: TyFun Nat *) :: *
type instance Apply (SplitHalf a) l = (Vec (2^l) a -> Vec (2^l) a, Vec (2 ^ (l + 1)) a -> Vec (2 ^ (l + 1)) a)

generateBitonicSortN2 :: forall k a . (Ord a, KnownNat k) => SNat k ->  Vec (2^k) a -> Vec (2^k) a
generateBitonicSortN2 k =  fst $ dfold (Proxy :: Proxy (SplitHalf a)) vecAcum base vecMath
  where
    vecMath = operationList k


vecAcum :: (KnownNat l, KnownNat gl,  Ord a) => SNat l
                                -> (SNat gl -> SplitHalf a @@ gl -> SplitHalf a @@ (gl+1))
                                -> SplitHalf a @@ l
                                -> SplitHalf a @@ (l+1)
vecAcum l0 f acc = undefined --  (f l0) acc

base :: (Ord a) => SplitHalf a @@ 0
base = (id,id)

general :: (KnownNat l,  Ord a)
        => SNat l
        -> SplitHalf a @@ l
        -> SplitHalf a @@ (l+1)
general _ (x,y) = (bitonicSort x y, bitonicMerge y )

operationList :: (KnownNat k, KnownNat l, Ord a)
              => SNat k
              -> Vec k
                   (SNat l
                 -> SplitHalf a @@ l
                 -> SplitHalf a @@ (l+1))
operationList k0 = replicate k0 general
```

I am using the extensions the dfold source code uses

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns         #-}

{-# LANGUAGE Trustworthy #-}
```

**Error Messages:**

```
   Sort.hs:182:71: error:
    * Could not deduce (KnownNat l) arising from a use of `vecAcum'
      from the context: (Ord a, KnownNat k)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   generateBitonicSortN2 :: (Ord a, KnownNat k) =>
                                            SNat k -> Vec (2 ^ k) a -> Vec (2 ^ k) a
        at Sort.hs:181:1-98
      Possible fix:
        add (KnownNat l) to the context of
          a type expected by the context:
            SNat l
            -> (SNat l0
                -> (Vec (2 ^ l0) a -> Vec (2 ^ l0) a,
                    Vec (2 ^ (l0 + 1)) a -> Vec (2 ^ (l0 + 1)) a)
                -> (Vec (2 ^ (l0 + 1)) a -> Vec (2 ^ (l0 + 1)) a,
                    Vec (2 ^ ((l0 + 1) + 1)) a -> Vec (2 ^ ((l0 + 1) + 1)) a))
            -> SplitHalf a @@ l
            -> SplitHalf a @@ (l + 1)
    * In the second argument of `dfold', namely `vecAcum'
      In the second argument of `($)', namely
        `dfold (Proxy :: Proxy (SplitHalf a)) vecAcum base vecMath'
      In the expression:
        fst $ dfold (Proxy :: Proxy (SplitHalf a)) vecAcum base vecMath

Sort.hs:182:84: error:
    * Could not deduce (KnownNat l0) arising from a use of `vecMath'
      from the context: (Ord a, KnownNat k)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   generateBitonicSortN2 :: (Ord a, KnownNat k) =>
                                            SNat k -> Vec (2 ^ k) a -> Vec (2 ^ k) a
        at Sort.hs:181:1-98
      The type variable `l0' is ambiguous
    * In the fourth argument of `dfold', namely `vecMath'
      In the second argument of `($)', namely
        `dfold (Proxy :: Proxy (SplitHalf a)) vecAcum base vecMath'
      In the expression:
        fst $ dfold (Proxy :: Proxy (SplitHalf a)) vecAcum base vecMath
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

** EDIT **
Added much more detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135612/discussion-between-lambdascientist-and-user2407038).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fill in (maybe the body of `generateBitonicSortN2`)? I'm having a tough time seeing which functions you give are hard constraints, which functions are part of your proposed solution, and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `base` case was wrong; it should be

```
base :: (Ord a) => SplitHalf a @@ 0
base = (id, bitonicMerge id)
```

Putting it all together, here's a fully working version, tested on GHC 8.0.2 (but it should work all the same on a GHC 8.0.2-based CLaSH, modulo the `Prelude` import stuff). It turns out the `operationList` thing is not used except for its spine, so we can use a `Vec n ()` instead.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.KnownNat.Solver #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-incomplete-patterns -fno-warn-redundant-constraints #-}

{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
import Prelude (Integer, (+), Num, ($), undefined, id, fst, Int, otherwise)
import CLaSH.Sized.Vector
import CLaSH.Promoted.Nat
import Data.Singletons
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Ord

type ExpVec k a = Vec (2 ^ k) a

data SplitHalf (a :: *) (f :: TyFun Nat *) :: *
type instance Apply (SplitHalf a) k = (ExpVec k a -> ExpVec k a, ExpVec (k + 1) a -> ExpVec (k + 1) a)

generateBitonicSortN2 :: forall k a . (Ord a, KnownNat k) => SNat k -> ExpVec k a -> ExpVec k a
generateBitonicSortN2 k = fst $ dfold (Proxy :: Proxy (SplitHalf a)) step base (replicate k ())
  where
    step :: SNat l -> () -> SplitHalf a @@ l -> SplitHalf a @@ (l+1)
    step SNat _ (sort, merge) = (bitonicSort sort merge, bitonicMerge merge)

    base = (id, bitonicMerge id)
```

This works as expected, e.g.:

```
*Main> generateBitonicSortN2  (snatProxy Proxy)  testVec2
<9,2>
*Main> generateBitonicSortN2  (snatProxy Proxy)  testVec4
<9,8,6,2>
*Main> generateBitonicSortN2  (snatProxy Proxy)  testVec8
<9,8,7,6,3,2,1,0>
*Main> generateBitonicSortN2  (snatProxy Proxy)  testVec16
<9,8,8,7,7,6,6,5,4,3,3,2,2,1,0,0>
*Main>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am using CLaSH to synthesis this to VHDL, so I cannot use recursion to apply t times

I don't understand this sentence, but other than that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances,
      FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, ConstraintKinds,
      UndecidableSuperClasses, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Proxy

data Peano = Z | S Peano

data SPeano n where
  SZ :: SPeano Z
  SS :: SPeano n -> SPeano (S n)

type family PowerOfTwo p where
  PowerOfTwo  Z    = 1
  PowerOfTwo (S p) = 2 * PowerOfTwo p

type family KnownPowersOfTwo p :: Constraint where
  KnownPowersOfTwo  Z    = ()
  KnownPowersOfTwo (S p) = (KnownNat (PowerOfTwo p), KnownPowersOfTwo p)

data Vec (n :: Nat) a -- abstract

type OnVec n a = Vec n a -> Vec n a
type GenBitonic n a = (OnVec n a, OnVec (2 * n) a)

genBitonic :: (Ord a, KnownNat n) => GenBitonic n a -> GenBitonic (2 * n) a
genBitonic = undefined

bitonicBase :: Ord a => GenBitonic 1 a
bitonicBase = undefined

genBitonicN :: (Ord a, KnownPowersOfTwo p) => SPeano p -> GenBitonic (PowerOfTwo p) a
genBitonicN  SZ    = bitonicBase
genBitonicN (SS p) = genBitonic (genBitonicN p)
```

`genBitonicN` is defined by recursion on the peano number which represents a power. At each recursive step a new `KnownNat (PowerOfTwo p)` pops up (via the `KnownPowersOfTwo` type family). At the value level `genBitonicN` is trivial and just does what you want. However we need some additional machinery in order to define a convenient `bSortN`:

```
type family Lit n where
  Lit 0 = Z
  Lit n = S (Lit (n - 1))

class IPeano n where
  speano :: SPeano n

instance IPeano Z where
  speano = SZ

instance IPeano n => IPeano (S n) where
  speano = SS speano

class (n ~ PowerOfTwo (PowerOf n), KnownPowersOfTwo (PowerOf n)) =>
         IsPowerOfTwo n where
  type PowerOf n :: Peano
  getPower :: SPeano (PowerOf n)

instance IsPowerOfTwo 1 where
  type PowerOf 1 = Lit 0
  getPower = speano

instance IsPowerOfTwo 2 where
  type PowerOf 2 = Lit 1
  getPower = speano

instance IsPowerOfTwo 4 where
  type PowerOf 4 = Lit 2
  getPower = speano

instance IsPowerOfTwo 8 where
  type PowerOf 8 = Lit 3
  getPower = speano

instance IsPowerOfTwo 16 where
  type PowerOf 16 = Lit 4
  getPower = speano

-- more powers go here

bSortN :: (IsPowerOfTwo n, Ord a) => OnVec n a
bSortN = fst $ genBitonicN getPower
```

Here are some examples:

```
bSort1 :: Ord a => OnVec 1 a
bSort1 = bSortN

bSort2 :: Ord a => OnVec 2 a
bSort2 = bSortN

bSort4 :: Ord a => OnVec 4 a
bSort4 = bSortN

bSort8 :: Ord a => OnVec 8 a
bSort8 = bSortN

bSort16 :: Ord a => OnVec 16 a
bSort16 = bSortN
```

I don't know whether we can avoid defining `IsPowerOfTwo` for each power of two.

Update: here is another variant of `bSortN`:

```
pnatToSPeano :: IPeano (Lit n) => proxy n -> SPeano (Lit n)
pnatToSPeano _ = speano

bSortNP :: (IPeano (Lit p), KnownPowersOfTwo (Lit p), Ord a)
        => proxy p -> OnVec (PowerOfTwo (Lit p)) a
bSortNP = fst . genBitonicN . pnatToSPeano
```

An example:

```
bSort16 :: Ord a => OnVec 16 a
bSort16 = bSortNP (Proxy :: Proxy 4)
```